# Arduino bulk programming

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm looking to see how I can program several Arduinos with the same code quickly. I have looked around and it seems you can do this by using a master Arduino that has the code on an SD card, but I can't find actual steps to accomplish this. Any direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a software programming question, but a hardware programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that the community voted down for the question. I still believe that this issue is software and can be solved by software.

In order to upload the firmware from the Arduino IDE simultaneously to several boards, you need to perform following steps:

1. Enable verbose output during upload in Arduino preferences
2. Upload sketch to board and look for avrdude path in the logs. (I highlighted it with green rectangle)
3. Now export compiled binary of the sketch

[image]

And then you can use a piece of shell scripting magic (for Linux):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

hex_file="/home/<username>/Documents/Arduino/<project_name>/<filename>.hex"
path_to_avrdude="<path to avrdude>"
serial_port_offset="/dev/ttyUSB*"

command_list=""

for port in $(find $serial_port_offset)
do
    command_list="${command_list} -C${path_to_avrdude}/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P${port} -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:${hex_file}:i"$'\n'
done

# Specify the count of your boards to -P argument
echo "$command_list" | xargs -n8 -P8 "${path_to_avrdude}/bin/avrdude"
```

And for Mac OS:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hex_file="/Users/<username>/Documents/Arduino/<project_name>/<filename>.hex"
path_to_avrdude="/Users/<username>/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9"
serial_port_offset="/dev/tty.wchusbserial*"

command_list=""

for port in $(find $serial_port_offset)
do
    command_list="${command_list} -C${path_to_avrdude}/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P${port} -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:${hex_file}:i"$'\n'
done

# Specify the count of your boards to -P argument
echo "$command_list" | xargs -n8 -P8 "${path_to_avrdude}/bin/avrdude"
```

This script will upload your hex file to all boards, connected to your PC. Make sure to change hex_file, path_to_avrdude and probably serial_port_offset, avrdude -p and -c parameters according to the Arduino output.

Comment: This is very helpful and right along the path I was hoping.  Would it be a similar syntax for Windows?  Thinking I can make a simple gui that would allow me to pick the program I want to upload to all devices or even a checklist of ports on the machine...

Comment: @berr08, I'm actually not well versed in windows scripting, but you can rewrite this script to windows. As you can see, the idea is quite simple: I'm generating desired avrdude commands for each board and then xargs performs these commands simultaneously. The GUI application for such a purpose looks like a good idea but definitely, out of the scope of stackoverflow question. Maybe someone will create a plugin for Arduino IDE after this question)